# Connect a C# Desktop Application on AWS via RDP

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, window, rdp

I have a C# Windows desktop application which use a cable connector to a hardware. The application should run in a full Windows instance.

The problem :
The application needs to be deployed on AWS and a client should be able to use Remote Desktop with virtual channel to connect to the application
When a client use Remote Desktop a new AWS instance should be started and when the client disconnect the instance should be stopped.

I saw 2 possible (incomplete) solutions:

- AWS WorkSpaces but this use as a connector an AWS client. Is not possible to use RDP (I think)
  And how I can start/stop/create a new instance ?
- AWS EC2. Can use RDP but I don't know if can start/stop/ create new instance with each connection.

Comment: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/connect-workspace-rdp

Comment: Thank you. Looks that is what I need. I will check it. But is is possible to start/stop a new instance ?